# <script src="X"></script> inside return render | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React how should i declare my scripts?

on HTML looks like:

```
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but how its work on React?

```
export default class Footerjq extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
    {/* jQuery */}
      script.src = "../assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      {/* Bootstrap */}
      script.src = "../assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    );
  }
}
```

I tried like this, but throw me an error...

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (9:6)

   7 |       script.src = "public/bundle.js",
   8 |       {/* jQuery */}
>  9 |       script.src = "../assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
     |       ^
```

Comment: You can just add your `<script>` tags as usual in top of your `index.html` or whatever root page you have :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not allow you to do this, but you should be able to do this in your component:

```
componentWillMount() {
  ['../jquery.js', '../bundle.js'].forEach((src) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  });
}
```

But why don't you simply embed them on your `index.html` though?

Comment: Just testing with react... i needed to know if react allows to do it. Thx!